# PrimitiveRoot function

Tags: number-theory, implementation-details

The function `PrimitiveRoot[n]` claims to return the **smallest** primitive root of `n`.  I believe this is not true.

For example `PrimitiveRoot[18]` returns `11`,  yet `5` is the smallest primitive root of `18`.

How does Mathematica select the particular primitive root that it returns under this function?

Comment: That may be because 18 is a composite number. [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRoot.html) states: "A primitive root of a number n (but not necessarily the smallest primitive root for composite n) can be computed in Mathematica using PrimitiveRoot[n]. "

Comment: Thanks! I have Mathematica 9.  There does not seem to be a function PrimitiveRootList.  Is this function "new in 10"? I can get a list of primitive roots with:  Select[Range[18], 
 CoprimeQ[#, 18] && MultiplicativeOrder[#, 18] == EulerPhi[18] &]   I would still like to know the answer to my original question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
s$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

```
PrimitiveRoot[18]
```

> 11

Although the documentation for [PrimitiveRoot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrimitiveRoot.html) states "PrimitiveRoot[n] gives the smallest primitive root of n"; as @Sjoerd pointed out in the comments, [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRoot.html) states: "A primitive root of a number n (but not necessarily the smallest primitive root for composite n) can be computed in Mathematica using PrimitiveRoot[n]. " Consequently, at a minimum there is a documentation error.

However, note that

```
PrimitiveRootList[18]
```

> {5, 11}

Consequently, a more robust method of finding the "smallest primitive root" would be `Min[PrimitiveRootList[n]]` (note that PrimitiveRootList is new to version 10).

Examples,

```
DeleteCases[
   {#, CompositeQ[#], PrimitiveRoot[#],
      Min[PrimitiveRootList[#]]} & /@ Range[2, 200],
   _?(#[[4]] === Infinity || #[[3]] == #[[4]] &)] //

  Prepend[#, {"n", "CompositeQ", "PrimitiveRoot[n]", "Minimum"}] & //
 Grid
```

[image]